# Why does doWork in CoroutineWorker hang when exception is thrown on bad login to FTP server?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ftp

I am trying to make a connection with an FTP server (vsftpd with SSL/TLS configured including implicit passive mode) and list all files in the "." directory. I use Android Studio with Kotlin.

Whenever I invoke the `enqueueTask(workManager)` and wait 10 seconds (initial delay of the worker), the FTP client connects to the vsftpd server succesfully but upon giving wrong user and pass credentials (which leads to the code throwing `ConnectException` due to `loggedIn` being false) the exception is not re-thrown immediately and only thrown after some minutes of waiting.

Why is this behaviour occuring and how to resolve it such that the exception is thrown as soon as it occurs so that it can be caught by the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` for retry?

`build.gradle` commons-net/workmanager dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
}
```

`PeriodicWorker` class:

```kotlin
class PeriodicWorker(
    appContext: Context,
    private val workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG: String = "PeriodicWorker"

        private const val TIME: Long = 3
        private val UNIT_TIME: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS

        fun enqueueTask(workManager: WorkManager) {
            val periodicWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<PeriodicWorker>(
                TIME, UNIT_TIME
            )
                .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // for testing purposes
                .setBackoffCriteria(
                    BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                    PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS
                )
                .build()

            workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("unique", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWork)
        }
    }

    private val ftpHandler: FtpHandler = FtpHandler()

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
              
                val filesInFtpServer: Array<String>? = ftpHandler.listFileNamesFtpServer() // Note: Should throw exception but doesn't immediately do that

                Result.success()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Result.retry()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ftpHandler` class:

```
class FtpHandler {

    companion object {
        private const val DATA_TIMEOUT_MS = 1000 * 5 
        private const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS = 1000 * 5
        private const val TAG = "FtpHandler"
    }
    
    private val client: FTPSClient = FTPSClient("TLS", true)
    private val ftpHost = ""
    private val ftpPort = 21
    private val ftpUsername = "wrong_user"
    private val ftpPassword = "wrong_pass"
    
    init {
        client.setDataTimeout(DATA_TIMEOUT_MS)
        client.connectTimeout = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS
    }
    
    private fun login(): Boolean {
        // Establish a connection with the FTP Server
        client.connect(ftpHost, ftpPort)

        client.execPBSZ(0)
        client.execPROT("P") 

        client.enterLocalPassiveMode()

        // Login with given username and pass
        return client.login(ftpUsername, ftpPassword)
    }
    
    fun listFileNamesFtpServer(directory: String = "."): Array<String>? {
        var res: Array<String>? = null
        
        try {
            val loggedIn: Boolean = login()

            if (loggedIn) {
                if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.replyCode)) {
                    client.changeWorkingDirectory(directory)
                    res = client.listNames()
                } else {
                    throw ConnectException("Reply: ${client.reply}")
                }
            } else {
                throw ConnectException("Reply: ${client.reply}")
            }
            
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        } finally {
            try {
                client.logout()
                client.disconnect()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                throw e
            }
        }
        
        return res
    }

}
```

I suspect it has to do with the timeouts of the FTP socket that might be interleaved at some points of the execution of `login` function. I tried using another test function that does dummy http request and waits 3000 milliseconds until it throws an Exception and even that immediately triggered exception and caught in the context Dispatchers.IO.

**UPDATE**:

I used the android studio debugger to see how the problem can be reproduced. If the FTP server is not online, the FTPS client would successfully throw SocketTimeoutException as expected in the coroutine scope.

However, when the FTP is online then the FTPS client IS able to make a connection it does not throw the mentioned exception but just hangs for a minute or two and then throws the exception. In this case, the vsftpd server responds with `"530 Login incorrect."` but the FTPSClient of commons-net does not disconnect afterwards.

**UPDATE 2**:

I added 5 seconds timeout to socket: `client.soTimeout = 5 * 1000` before calling `return client.login(ftpUsername, ftpPassword)`.

Doing that, the exception thrown is `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` after the `throw ConnectException()` is thrown when `loggedIn` is false.

I find this strange. Why doesn't `listFileNamesFtpServer` immediately execute `throw e` after `ConnectException` is thrown? Why is it that it waits for a read from FTP server and when socket timeout is reached it goes into the catch block of the method which propagates the exception successfully to the coroutine call?

Comment: Something is probably wrong with `ftpHandler.listFileNamesFtpServer()`. I'm not familiar with that class. Can you share the source code of that function? It's probably not cooperating with coroutine cancellation somehow.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It is in the code section underneath the worker class. I have updated the code for clarity.

Comment: I think it's because it has to wait for `finally` block to complete. Maybe `client.logout()` and/or `client.disconnect()` takes longer time.

Comment: Hi @ltp could you please check the update sections of the thread?

Comment: Why is it that it waits for a read from FTP server and when socket timeout is reached it goes into the catch block of the method which propagates the exception successfully to the coroutine call - I think since it causes `client.logout()` to immediately throw an exception too.  Another thing, I think another try catch in finally block is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the culprit of the hanging behaviour is that the FTP socket was trying to read a reply from the FTP server while there wasn't any. The exception got thrown later on since I use the `.reply` function of FTPSClient within the exception string. When the exception was thrown hence depended on the `So_timeout` value of the ftpclient.

Solution: instead use `getReplyCode` , `getReplyString` , and `getReplyStrings` (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) To get the latest replycode/string/strings that the FTP responded in the latest response.

I don't know the exact reason why they allowed the user to use the reply function and did not make it private or protected instead.

Thanks android studio debugger, @ltp and @Tenfour04 for your efforts!